# ToDate Should not be Less than FromDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have two datepicker one is for Fromdate and second is for Todate. I want ToDate should not be less then Fromdate. I have tried to solve this but i am not able to solve this properly.

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.datepicker', function() {
            // alert();
            $(this).datepicker({
                 format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
    //startDate: '-90d',
    //endDate: '+0d',
                autoclose: true

            });
   
   $(".datepickerInputTO").change(function () {
    var fromDate = $(".datepickerInputFROM").val;
    var toDate = $(".datepickerInputTO").val;
 
    if (toDate <= fromDate) {
        alert("End date should be greater than Start date");
        $(".datepickerInputTO").val = "";
    }
});
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css"></script>

<div class="col-md-3">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Select from Date" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium datepicker datepickerInputFROM">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Select to Date" class="form-control form-control-inline input-medium datepicker datepickerInputTO">
      </div>
```

Comment: `.val()` returns a string.

Comment: could you please help in this ?

Comment: and `.val` returns a function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it `changeDate`, here you can change `todate` if `fromdate` is changed to some larger date value as:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepickerInputFROM").datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: 1,
        //startDate: new Date(),
        todayHighlight: false,
        endDate: new Date()
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
        $('.datepickerInputTO').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
        $(".datepickerInputTO").val($(".datepickerInputFROM").val());
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });

    $(".datepickerInputTO").datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        todayHighlight: true,
        endDate: new Date()
    }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/915/)**

Comment: Please put your code in jsfiddle , I will edit that.. ;)

Comment: please check the demo

Comment: Currently in the demo I have disabled future dates...you can customize it to your requirements...just remove `endDate`

Comment: hey @Pawan is it possible that we can disable "Todate"  untill user selects "FromDate" ?

Comment: yes..disable `todate` by default and enable that on `changeDate` of `fromDate`..like `$(".datepickerInputTO").removeAttr("disabled")`...http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/917/

Comment: HI Pawan , I need one more samll help in this datepicker issue. If i select Any date in March in FromDate then in ToDate we are able to select dates from selected date of FromDate but now if i select some date in April month in FromDate then still Todate is having March date. I Have updated my script in below fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/arpitmufc/uk3p5g7o/ can we solve this issue ?